# Excel VBA - Split Each Line and Calulate Value

Tags: vba, excel

I have multiple lines in on cell that follow the following format

```
12/1/2013-$590.00
10/1/2014-$602.00
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is get the script to read the number after the dollar sign and take the highest one and verify it is higher then the current rent and if it is then change it to the new one.

I have tried to use the following code but am having some problems.
Any help would be much appreciated

```
'Start Rent Update check
' First, lets check if the text in the pointed cell is divided into separate rows at all
' If this is not the case, we will display the whole text
WhereFrom = NewRent



Temporary = InStr(WhereFrom, Chr(10))
MsgBox (Temporary)
If Temporary = 0 Then
    GetTextRow = WhereFrom ' return text from pointed cell
    intPos = InStr(1, GetTextRow, "$")

        If intPos > 0 Then
            MsgBox ("Storage Variable " & StorageVariable)
            StorageVariable = CInt(Right(GetTextRow, Len(GetTextRow) - intPos))
            If StorageVariable > 100 Then
                If StorageVariable > Rent Then
                      Rent = StorageVariable
                End If

            Else
                Parking = StorageVariable
            End If

        End If
Else
    ' lets also check if the row number the user provided is not too big.

    TemporaryArray = Split(WhereFrom, Chr(10))
    Do While Not (RowNumber - 1 > UBound(TemporaryArray) Or _
    RowNumber = 0)
    ' if everything is all right the function returns (displays) the chosen row
        GetTextRow = TemporaryArray(RowNumber - 1)
         intPos = InStr(1, GetTextRow, "$")
         MsgBox (intPos)
        If intPos > 0 Then
            MsgBox (StorageVariable)
            StorageVariable = CInt(Right(GetTextRow, Len(GetTextRow) - intPos))
            If StorageVariable > 100 Then
                If StorageVariable > Rent Then
                      Rent = StorageVariable
                End If

            Else
                Parking = StorageVariable
            End If
                 RowNumber = RowNumber + 1
        End If
    Loop
    End If
'Check end of rent update
```

Comment: so what is the actual question/problem?

Comment: It isnt currently working, the numbers arent replacing the lesser numbers that are currently stored in the rent variable

Comment: I've never trusted my calculations with `right` - I would use `StorageVariable = CInt(mid(GetTextRow, intPos+1))` (the +1 to avoid the $ sign)

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the highest rent in a cell, you can use this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim MyAr, tmpAr
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Rent As Double

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws.Range("A1")
        If InStr(1, .Value, "$") Then
            MyAr = Split(.Value, Chr(10))

            For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
                If InStr(1, MyAr(i), "$") Then
                    tmpAr = Split(MyAr(i), "$")

                    If Val(Trim(tmpAr(UBound(tmpAr)))) > Rent Then _
                    Rent = Val(Trim(tmpAr(UBound(tmpAr))))

                End If
            Next i
        End If
    End With

    Debug.Print Rent
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

[image]